# Recycler View custom scrolling effects

Tags: android

I want to make awesome scroll effect. I've found a couple of examples:

http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/

but I have no idea how to such behaviour. I consider to make it on my own, but it will be good to have a library which I can use. Just need some starting point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this library a few times and seemed good but seems to be in need of an update since some of the delete animations have problems. But the scrolling animations should still be good:

https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators